# Is there a way to put negative floats in a QSpinBox?

Tags: python, qt, qtreeview, qitemdelegate

I am trying to find a way to put negative numbers in a `QDoubleSpinBox`. I read the documentation but haven't found the solution yet. Here is the class I made to customize my `QDoubleSpinBox` :

```py
class ComboBoxDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
    """A delegate that allows the user to change integer values from the model
       using a spin box widget. """

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index : QModelIndex):
        if index.column() == 0 :
            editor = QLineEdit(parent)
            return editor
        

        if index.column() == 1 :
            combo = QComboBox(parent)
            combo.addItems(["len","diam","conc"])
            editor = combo
            
            return editor
        
        if index.column() > 1 :
            editor = CustomDoubleSpinbox(parent)
            editor.setDecimals(3)
            return editor

    def setEditorData(self, editor , index):
        value = index.model().data(index, Qt.EditRole)
        if type(editor) == QComboBox :
            editor.setCurrentText(str(value))

        if type(editor) == CustomDoubleSpinbox :
            editor.setValue(value)

        if type(editor) == QLineEdit :
            editor.setText(value)

    def setModelData(self, editor , model, index : QModelIndex):
        if type(editor) == QComboBox :
            value = editor.currentText()
        if type(editor) == CustomDoubleSpinbox :
            editor.interpretText()
            value = editor.value()
        if type(editor) == QLineEdit :
            value = editor.text()
        model.setData(index, value, Qt.EditRole)

    def updateEditorGeometry(self, editor, option, index):
        editor.setGeometry(option.rect)





class CustomDoubleSpinbox(QDoubleSpinBox):
    def validate(self, text: str, pos: int) -> object:
        text = text.replace(".", ",")
        return QDoubleSpinBox.validate(self, text, pos)

    def valueFromText(self, text: str) -> float:
        text = text.replace(",", ".")
        return float(text)
```

**EDIT**
h4z3 found the solution in the documentation : [QDoubleSpinBox for python](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-5/PySide2/QtWidgets/QDoubleSpinBox.html). By setting a negative minimum with the `setMinimum` method, it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[As docs say:](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-5/PySide2/QtWidgets/QDoubleSpinBox.html#PySide2.QtWidgets.PySide2.QtWidgets.QDoubleSpinBox)

> Constructs a spin box with 0.0 as minimum value and 99.99 as maximum value, a step value of 1.0 and a precision of 2 decimal places.

But just below there's:

> See also setMinimum() setMaximum() setSingleStep()

[The linked setMinimum docs](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-5/PySide2/QtWidgets/QDoubleSpinBox.html#PySide2.QtWidgets.PySide2.QtWidgets.QDoubleSpinBox.setMinimum)

So since you're inheriting from QDoubleSpinBox, it would be the best to modify this in init:

```py
class CustomDoubleSpinbox(QDoubleSpinBox):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)  # to not break inheritance
        self.setMinimum(-99.99)  # we inherited the method, so we can now set our own minimum to be used

    def validate(self, text: str, pos: int) -> object:
        text = text.replace(".", ",")
        return QDoubleSpinBox.validate(self, text, pos)

    def valueFromText(self, text: str) -> float:
        text = text.replace(",", ".")
        return float(text)
```

This way, every time you create the object of CustomDoubleSpinbox class, the minimum will be always changed - as opposed to using setMinimum somewhere else in the code.

The *args and **kwargs are a way to ensure the code doesn't break if signature changes. In this case, QDoubleSpinBox only takes optional parent and we could just hardcode it. But I like pretty and flexible code. (You can switch those two lines to `def __init__(self, parent=None):` and `super().__init__(parent)` - it will be the same. Just remember that setting min needs to be after the super, not before.)

You could also [use setRange to be explicit about both min and max](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-5/PySide2/QtWidgets/QDoubleSpinBox.html#PySide2.QtWidgets.PySide2.QtWidgets.QDoubleSpinBox.setRange) (because max is now not obvious without reading docs).

I also used -99.99 in setMinimum to match default max of 99.99 - but of course you might want to adjust that value as well.